# Change the z-index of a chosen div on menu selection

Tags: jquery, gallery, z-index

I have seen some question that ask how to change the z-index on the same div, but not on how to apply this to a different div. I don't have enough knowledge of javascript to know the exact way to do this, but I suppose it is possible.

This is what I want to do :

I have the following page in progress : http://maevamaurel.com/book.html

There are two menus in this page, the main menu, and a sub menu allowing the user to browse the artist's work. What I'm trying to do is to have the different galleries change z-index when the corresponding sub menu button is selected (Web/Corporate/ etc...). Thus, when the Web button is selected, the corresponding gallerie is brought up on front. I know it is not the best way to code it maybe, but any suggestions are welcome.

Would that work btw? I'm thinking ight know it might not once all the galleries have the same z-index (I'm confused, I've been working on this particular page forever, I'd do a php/sql combo but the user has no clue how to access the admin page so I only have ftp access).

Any help is appreciated.

Addendum :

Here is the code I have (I only have HTML code btw)

```
<div id="menu_book">
            <a href="" id="web">Web</a>
            <a href="" id="corporate">Corporate</a>
            <a href="" id="print">Print</a>
            <a href="" id="perso">Perso</a>
            <a href="" id="projetpro">Projet Pro.</a>
    </div>
```

Thats the menu code

```
<div id="tab_web">
            <img src="img/Page_Book/images_book/image_web/site_1_preview.png" alt="Test description" data-description="Test description for image 1">
            <img src="img/Page_Book/images_book/image_web/site_2_preview.png">
            <img src="img/Page_Book/images_book/image_web/site_3_preview.png">
            <img src="img/Page_Book/images_book/image_web/site_4_preview.png">
            <img src="img/Page_Book/images_book/image_web/site_5_preview.png">
            <img src="img/Page_Book/images_book/image_web/site_6_preview.png">
            <img src="img/Page_Book/images_book/image_web/site_7_preview.png">
            <img src="img/Page_Book/images_book/image_web/site_8_preview.png">
            <script>
                Galleria.loadTheme('galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
                Galleria.run('#tab_web');
            </script>
        </div>
```

That is the div code (I am using the Galleria plugin)

Oh and the corresponding code for the gallery tab is this :

```
#tab_web {
position:absolute;
display:block;
height:62%;
width:48%;
left:17%;
top:18%;
z-index:400;
```

}

I only put the code for one of each as they are all the same. Would it help if I omitted the z-index of the gallery tabs? They are inside another div so it wouldn't affect them much.

**Update** : I got it to work, only issue is that the other galleries keep their z-index values. Now I have been thinking algorithm wise, and this is what I think could work:

1. I give each of the ids a class, say '.Galleria'
2. I modify the javascript to turn it into a function, where function(id,value).
3. When the function is called, it will call all elements having the class '.Galleria' and modify the given id's z-index by the chosen value. All other values belonging to the same class but not the same id will then have their z-index values reduced to a lower value.

I have a general idea on how to do this, so I will try to write a function once I eat breakfast (no use on trying to think on an empty stomach), but if you can give me some pointers I'd appreciate it.

I think I have to use something akin to  $(this).elementbyId or something like that?

I need to see the javascript api documentation.

**Code update**

While my breakfast simmers and cooks, I wrote this function rather hastily. I am not sure if it will work, I have yet to test it, but I figure I'd get your input before and after I male corrections (always useful when learning)

The function :

```
function changeIndex(gallerie,id) {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(gallerie),i;
    for (i in elements) {
        if (elements = id) {
            $(elements).css('zIndex',400);
        }
        else {
            $(elements).css('zIndex',200);
        }
    }
}
```

Anything that might not work there?

Comment: Please paste the relevant code in here. That way if someone has this same question in the future they can find the information even if your linked site changes.

Comment: Some specific code would be nice, because it is no problem to set the "z-index" of any object with jQuery ... you only need to know, how to select the right one (finding the right selector for your need).

Comment: as you are using jquery you can use `$('#idOfdiv').css('z-index', 1)` to change the `z-index` then add this to the onclick of whatever button you click

Comment: now just to be clear, by button you also mean any <a> tag element right?

Comment: @Pete you forgot camel-casing `$('#idOfdiv').css('zIndex', 1)`

Comment: Well I tried it and it works for about .5 seconds, then it reloads and has all the galleries bunch one on top of another. I checked with firebug and it does not seem to apply the css change for more than the click. I used the following markup `code` <a href="" id="web" onClick="$('#tab_web').css('zIndex',400)">Web</a> `code`

Comment: Please see update for the function I wrote